# Ruby on Rails QR-Code with RQRCode-Gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I'm trying to implement a two-factor-authentication for my Rails application and the tokens work fine, but the QR-Code isn't.

I want to create the provisioning_uri inside the code and therefore I'm using the RQRCode-Gem, which is recommended for this.

So basically I did everything like it's mentioned in the GitHub-Repo, but I don't get it working.

In my Gemfile I added:

```
gem 'active_model_otp'
gem 'rqrcode'
```

Then in my UsersController, I'm creating a new instance of the QR-Code library and passing in the parameters (show-Action):

```
@qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(@user.provisioning_uri, :size => 8, :level => :h)
```

And then, like it's written in the Readme, I added the table for my QR-Code in my view:

```
<table class="qr">
      <% @qr.modules.each_index do |x| %>
          <tr>
            <% @qr.modules.each_index do |y| %>
                <% if @qr.dark?(x,y) %>
                    <td class="black">
                <% else %>
                    <td class="white">
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
```

I also added the necessary styles to my application.scss:

```
.qr {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: #0000ff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .qr td {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: #0000ff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .qr td.black { background-color: #000; }
  .qr td.white { background-color: #fff; }
```

So I don't think there is any fault from my side, at least I can't seem to find it.

If I run my application now and enter my show-Page I get the following error:

[image]

It looks like my application can't find the resource or something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's `#dark?` ?

Comment: can you please update your question to links to the gem documentation?  Since you already looked at that it would save us guess work finding it.

Comment: but the error is telling you exactly that there is no method defined on the object you're calling it on.  So `@qr` has no defined `dark?` method.  I couldn't find any such method at https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode if that's the gem you're using.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering aswell. That's my source:
https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp/wiki/Generate-QR-code-with-rqrcode-gem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it myself by rendering the QR-Code as PNG and show it with the chuny_png gem's to_data_url method. Just in case somebody gets the same problem! :)

Comment: always try to enough info o your answer that any user can get understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="qr">
  <%= @qr.as_html.html_safe %>
</div>
```

Comment: Tries to add more inforamtino about your answer, and not just the code answer, maybe docs or some text about it

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
<table class="qr">
  <% @qr.modules.each do |x| %>
      <tr>
        <% x.each do |y| %>
            <% if y %>
                <td class="black">
            <% else %>
                <td class="white">
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```